# backbone.js update one view based on events in another?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have the following HTML code:

```
<ul id='item-list'></ul>
<button id='add-item'>Add Item</button>
<script type='text/template' id='item-template'>
  <li><%= title %></li>
</script>
```

and the following javascript / backbone js code:

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var ItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Item
});


var ItemListView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el : $("#item-list"),
   initialize(options) {
     this.item_collection = new ItemCollection();
   }, 
   appendItem: function() {
     new_item = new Item({'title' : 'New Item'});
     this.item_collection.add(new_item);
     item_template = $("#item-template");
     item_html = _.template(item_template,new_item.toJSON());
     this.el.append(item_html);
   }
});

var AddItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $("add-item"),
  events: {
    "click" : "addItem"
  },
  addItem: function() {
    // ?
  }
});

item_list_view = new ListItemView();
add_item_view = new AddItemView();
```

How can I add a new item to the item list view and collection from an event in the addItemView View? also, should the creation of the model, appending it to the collection, and appending it to the view all take place in the `ListItemView.addItem()` function, or should I instead have it binded to the add event of the ItemCollection ? I am still having some trouble wrapping my head around the way bindings and the interactions between various views, models, and collections should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's an example of events between 2 views working with a model/collection.   Basically, use collectionName.bind('add',yourFunction,this);

```
    <script type="text/template" id="item-template">
      <div class="nonedit"><span ><%= name %> (<%= age %>)</span> <a class="delete" href="#">X</a>
      <div class="edit"><input /></div>

    </script>
    <body>
        <ul class="1"></ul>
        <div class="count">
            <div></div>
            <input id="name" placeholder="enter a name"/>
            <input id="age" placeholder="enter age"/>
        </div>

    </body>
```

---

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:function(){
        return {
            name:'unknown',
            age:0   
        };
    }
});

var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Person
});

var people = new People;

var Li = Backbone.View.extend({
    tag:'li',
    class:'name',
    template:_.template($('#item-template').html()),
    events:{
        'click a.delete':'remove'
    },
    initialize:function(){
        this.model.bind('change',this.render,this);
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    },
    render:function(){
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.attributes));  
    },
    remove:function(){
        this.model.destroy();
        $(this.el).fadeOut(300);
        setTimeout(function(){$(this.el).remove()},400);
    },
    modify:function(){
        $(this.el).addClass('edit');
    }
});

var Ul = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$('ul'),
    events:{

    },
    initialize:function(){
        people.bind('add',this.add,this);
    },
    render:function(){

    },
    add:function(model){
        var li = new Li({model:model});
        this.el.append(li.el);
    }


});

var ul = new Ul;



var Div = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$('.count'),
    nameInput:$('#name'),
    ageInput:$('#age'),
    events:{
        'keypress input#name':'keypress',
        'keypress input#age':'keypress',
    },
    initialize:function(){
        people.bind('add',this.add,this);
    },
    render:function(){

    },
    add:function(e){
        this.el.find('div').html(people.length);
    },
    keypress:function(event){
        if(event.which == 13){
            people.add({name:this.nameInput.val(),age:this.ageInput.val()});
        }
    }
});

var div = new Div;
```

Comment: thanks! couple questions: where does the this.model comes from in your li view? also, this looks like I should set up a third view in my example, for the individual task objects, is that correct?

Comment: The third view I created (div) is to illustrate how multiple views can bind to the same collection.  UL binds to people('add') to create new li's and div binds to people('add') to count and display the total.   

this.model is the model that the view is associated with.  It's created when I went var li = new Li({model:model});   


(Woops, I accidentally left 2 events in the div view, which dont' do anything...I was going to make the div have input form fields for adding new people.)

Comment: Fantastic answer... awesome!